# Call method with parameters

Tags: c#, methods

I am working through learning C# on my own - this is not a homework assignment.  I am only on chapter 7 so I am hoping for a simple/basic answer.

I am having troubles calling the TalentListing method from Main that gets its parameters from another method.  Do I have to duplicate them in the Main method?

I realize the methods are void - I don't need them to return anything, I just need them to run.

Sorry the code is long, I thought it would be best to show it all.

Thank you!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int pastContestants;
        int currentContestants;

        // Call Methods:
        Console.Write("LAST YEAR'S TALENT:  ");
        pastContestants = Contestants();

        Console.Write("THIS YEAR'S TALENT:  ");
        currentContestants = Contestants();
        Overview(pastContestants, currentContestants);
        CompetitorTalents(currentContestants);

        // need to call the TalentListing Method...

        TalentListing(CompetitorTalents(contestantNames), CompetitorTalents(validTalentCodes), CompetitorTalents(contestantTalentCodes);

        Console.ReadLine();         
     }

    public static int Contestants()
    { // Get & returns valid # of contestants.  Called twice - last year & this year

        int contestants = 0; // holds return value
        const int MIN = 0;  // will allow 0 as an answer
        const int MAX = 30;  // will allow 30 as an answer          

        Console.Write("Please enter the number of contestants:  ");
        contestants = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (contestants < MIN || contestants > MAX)
        {
            Console.Write("Invalid number.  Please enter a number between 0 and 30, inclusive:  ");
            contestants = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        return contestants;
    }

    public static void Overview(int past, int current)
    { // Accepts contestant - past & current.  Displays 1 of 3 messages.
        double entranceFee = 25.00;

        Console.WriteLine("\nWe had {0} contestants last year and have {1} contestants this year.", past,
                           current);

        //if more than double
        if (current > (past * 2))
            Console.WriteLine("The competition is more than twice as big this year!");

        //if bigger but no more than double
        if (current > past && current < (past * 2))
            Console.WriteLine("The competition is bigger than ever!");

        //if smaller than last year
        if (current < past)
            Console.WriteLine("A tighter race this year.  Come out and cast your vote!");

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe revenue expected for this year is {0:C}.", current * entranceFee);
    }

    public static void CompetitorTalents(int current)
    { // Fill array of competitors and their talent codes.

        string[] contestantNames;
        string contestantNameEntered;// user entry
        char[] contestantTalentCodes;
        char talentCodeEntered; // user entry
        string[] talents = { "Dancing", "Musical", "Other" };
        char[] validTalentCodes = { 'D', 'M', 'O' };
        int[] total = new int[talents.Length];
        bool validCode = false;
        int counter = 0;

        contestantNames = new string[current]; // set array size
        contestantTalentCodes = new char[current]; // set array size

        // put contestants in array
        while (counter < current)// loop for all contestants
        {
            // get contenstants name and put in array
            Console.Write("Please enter the name of contestant:   ");
            contestantNameEntered = Console.ReadLine();
            counter += 1; // contestant number
            validCode = false;

            //place in correct array element
            contestantNames[counter - 1] = contestantNameEntered;

            // get contestants talent code, verify and place in array
            while (validCode == false) // reset per contestant
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the contestant's talent code (D=Dancing, M=Musical, O=Other):  ");
                talentCodeEntered = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());  // convert to uppercase
                for (int x = 0; x < validTalentCodes.Length && !validCode; ++x)

                    if (talentCodeEntered == validTalentCodes[x]) // talent code valid?
                    {
                        validCode = true; // true if match found
                        contestantTalentCodes[counter - 1] = talentCodeEntered; //put talent code in array
                        x = validTalentCodes.Length;  // breaks out of loop
                    }
                if (validCode == false)  // false if no match found = invalid code.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid code talent Code.");
                }
            }
        }

        // search all elements of validTalentCodes array (D, M, O), count instances in contestantTalentCodes array
        for (int z = 0; z < validTalentCodes.Length; z++) // validTalentCodes
            for (int x = 0; x < contestantTalentCodes.Length; x++) // contestantTalentCodes
                if (contestantTalentCodes[x] == validTalentCodes[z])
                {
                    total[z]++;
                }
        for (int x = 0; x < talents.Length; ++x)
            Console.WriteLine("Total contenstants for {0} is {1}.", talents[x], total[x]);
    }

    public static void TalentListing(string contestantNames, char [] validTalentCodes, char [] contestantTalentCodes)
    { // Continuously prompt for talent codes and display contestants with the corresponding talent until quit.
        // What talent code would you like to see (or QUIT)?

        const char QUIT = 'Q';// must be upper as char are converted!!
        char userOption = ' ';
        bool validCode = false;

        while (userOption != QUIT)
        {
            Console.Write("\nWhat talent code would you like to view? (D, M, O or Q to quit):  ");
            validCode = false;  // reset from previous section
            userOption = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

            for (int x = 0; x < contestantNames.Length && !validCode; ++x)
            {
                if (userOption == validTalentCodes[x]) // valid talent code?
                {
                    validCode = true;
                    Console.Write("The contestants in {0} talent are: ", validTalentCodes[x]);

                    // display list of contestants with that code
                    for (int z = 0; z < contestantTalentCodes.Length; z++) // validTalentCodes
                        if (contestantTalentCodes[z] == userOption)
                        {
                            Console.Write("\n{0}", contestantNames[z]);
                        }
                }
            }
            if (validCode == false)
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid talent code!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();  // when QUIT is selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple app use static global variables. Just copy this code and take a look.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        public static string[] talents = { "Dancing", "Musical", "Other" };
        public static char[] validTalentCodes = { 'D', 'M', 'O' };
        public static string[] contestantNames;
        public static char[] contestantTalentCodes;

        static void Main()
    {
        int pastContestants;
        int currentContestants;

        // Call Methods:
        Console.Write("LAST YEAR'S TALENT:  ");
        pastContestants = Contestants();

        Console.Write("THIS YEAR'S TALENT:  ");
        currentContestants = Contestants();
        Overview(pastContestants, currentContestants);

        CompetitorTalents(currentContestants);
        // need to call the TalentListing Method...
        TalentListing();
        Console.ReadLine();         
     }

        public static int Contestants()
        { // Get & returns valid # of contestants.  Called twice - last year & this year

            int contestants = 0; // holds return value
            const int MIN = 0;  // will allow 0 as an answer
            const int MAX = 30;  // will allow 30 as an answer          

            Console.Write("Please enter the number of contestants:  ");
            contestants = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while (contestants < MIN || contestants > MAX)
            {
                Console.Write("Invalid number.  Please enter a number between 0 and 30, inclusive:  ");
                contestants = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return contestants;
        }

        public static void Overview(int past, int current)
        { // Accepts contestant - past & current.  Displays 1 of 3 messages.
            double entranceFee = 25.00;

            Console.WriteLine("\nWe had {0} contestants last year and have {1} contestants this year.", past,
                               current);

            //if more than double
            if (current > (past * 2))
                Console.WriteLine("The competition is more than twice as big this year!");

            //if bigger but no more than double
            if (current > past && current < (past * 2))
                Console.WriteLine("The competition is bigger than ever!");

            //if smaller than last year
            if (current < past)
                Console.WriteLine("A tighter race this year.  Come out and cast your vote!");

            Console.WriteLine("\nThe revenue expected for this year is {0:C}.", current * entranceFee);
        }

        public static void CompetitorTalents(int current)
        { // Fill array of competitors and their talent codes.

            string contestantNameEntered;// user entry
            char talentCodeEntered; // user entry
            int[] total = new int[talents.Length];
            bool validCode = false;
            int counter = 0;

            contestantNames = new string[current]; // set array size
            contestantTalentCodes = new char[current]; // set array size

            // put contestants in array
            while (counter < current)// loop for all contestants
            {
                // get contenstants name and put in array
                Console.Write("Please enter the name of contestant:   ");
                contestantNameEntered = Console.ReadLine();
                counter += 1; // contestant number
                validCode = false;

                //place in correct array element
                contestantNames[counter - 1] = contestantNameEntered;

                // get contestants talent code, verify and place in array
                while (validCode == false) // reset per contestant
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter the contestant's talent code (D=Dancing, M=Musical, O=Other):  ");
                    talentCodeEntered = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());  // convert to uppercase
                    for (int x = 0; x < validTalentCodes.Length && !validCode; ++x)

                        if (talentCodeEntered == validTalentCodes[x]) // talent code valid?
                        {
                            validCode = true; // true if match found
                            contestantTalentCodes[counter - 1] = talentCodeEntered; //put talent code in array
                            x = validTalentCodes.Length;  // breaks out of loop
                        }
                    if (validCode == false)  // false if no match found = invalid code.
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid code talent Code.");
                    }
                }
            }

            // search all elements of validTalentCodes array (D, M, O), count instances in contestantTalentCodes array
            for (int z = 0; z < validTalentCodes.Length; z++) // validTalentCodes
                for (int x = 0; x < contestantTalentCodes.Length; x++) // contestantTalentCodes
                    if (contestantTalentCodes[x] == validTalentCodes[z])
                    {
                        total[z]++;
                    }
            for (int x = 0; x < talents.Length; ++x)
                Console.WriteLine("Total contenstants for {0} is {1}.", talents[x], total[x]);

            return ;
        }


        /// Continuously prompt for talent codes and display contestants with the corresponding talent until quit.
        /// What talent code would you like to see (or QUIT)?
        public static void TalentListing()
        { 
            const char QUIT = 'Q';// must be upper as char are converted!!
            char userOption = ' ';
            bool validCode = false;

            while (userOption != QUIT)
            {
                Console.Write("\nWhat talent code would you like to view? (D, M, O or Q to quit):  ");
                validCode = false;  // reset from previous section
                userOption = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

                for (int x = 0; x < contestantNames.Length && !validCode; ++x)
                {
                    if (userOption == validTalentCodes[x]) // valid talent code?
                    {
                        validCode = true;
                        Console.Write("The contestants in {0} talent are: ", validTalentCodes[x]);

                        // display list of contestants with that code
                        for (int z = 0; z < contestantTalentCodes.Length; z++) // validTalentCodes
                            if (contestantTalentCodes[z] == userOption)
                            {
                                Console.Write("\n{0}", contestantNames[z]);
                            }
                    }
                }
                if (validCode == false)
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid talent code!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();  // when QUIT is selected
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CompetitorTalents(int current)` method has no return value, you are using `void`. The `TalentListing` receives two `string`s. So you need to get those two from somewhere. If you want them to come from the `CompetitorTalens` method, you have to change it so it returns `string` and actually return something from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the method call (So you were missing a ) at the end) :

```
TalentListing(CompetitorTalents(contestantNames), CompetitorTalents(validTalentCodes), CompetitorTalents(contestantTalentCodes));
```

The methods you are calling are void meaning they dont return anything:

```
public static string CompetitorTalents(int current)
```

Then in the method call for the CompetitorTalents you should pass in what is the method needs.  I would advise doing this on separate lines:

```
string contestantNames = CompetitorTalents(currentContestants);
```

And so on, then in the TalentListing you could just reference the individual variables:

```
TalentListing(contestantNames, validTalentCodes, contestantTalentCodes);
```

Comment: I set them as void as I don't want them to return anything, I just want them to run.  Can I still leave them as void?

Comment: Well to be able to get out the parameters for the TalentListing, they need to return a string so you can pass them into that method.  Otherwise the other method does not know what the values are.

Comment: validTalendCodes and contestantTalentCodes are arrays, will that work if I use the method you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at your method signatures we can see the following:

**void TalentListing(string, char[], char[])**

**void CompetitorTalents(int)**

Your `CompetitorTalents` method returns a void, but you are trying to pass the result of that method as parameters for your `TalentListing` method. So you are essentially trying to call `TalentListing(void, void, void)`, when really it wants a `string`, a `char[]`, and then another `char[]`